# How do I show error bars in a ggplot bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to show error bars based on a chi squared test in my ggplot visualization.

Here is my data

```
version <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
group <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
values <- c("100", "2000", "500", "800",
            "110", "2500", "800", "1100")

data.frame(version, group, values) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, values, fill = version, label = values)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(position = "dodge")
```

Here is the chart without bars

[image]

I'd like error bars that are based on a chi squared test, like the one [here](https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/chi-squared.html).

Answer (score 2):

To add error bar, you need to use `geom_errorbar` for plotting and to add the `sd` to your dataframe.

Here a quick example with the `mtcars` dataset :

```r
library(dplyr)
df = mtcars[c(1:50),]
df = df[!is.na(df$cyl),]
df = df %>% 
  select(., mpg,cyl,gear) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(mpg), Sd = sd(mpg))
df

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  gear  Mean     Sd
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4     3  21.5 NA    
2     4     4  26.9  4.81 
3     4     5  28.2  3.11 
4     6     3  19.8  2.33 
5     6     4  19.8  1.55 
6     6     5  19.7 NA    
7     8     3  15.0  2.77 
8     8     5  15.4  0.566
```

And now the plotting part:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = Mean, fill = as.factor(gear))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean-Sd, ymax = Mean+Sd),width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: How do I set the error bars to be the 95% confidence interval from bootstrap resampling?

Comment: You just have to replace the `sd` column by the 95% confidence interval calculated from bootstrap resampling (depending what is your formula to calculate it)